# Global variable inline assignment with combined declaration/assignment operator and another undeclared variable losing scope?

Tags: go

This Go program will not compile. It throws the error `global_var declared and not used`

```
package main

import "log"

var global_var int

func main() {

    global_var, new_string := returnTwoVars()

    log.Println("new_string: " + new_string)
}

func returnTwoVars() (int, string) {
    return 1234, "woohoo"
}

func usesGlobalVar() int {
    return global_var * 2
}
```

However, when I remove the need for using the `:=` operator by declaring `new_string` in the main function and simply using `=`, the compiler doesn't have a problem with seeing that `global_var` is declared globally and being used elsewhere in the program. My intuition tells me that it should know that `global_var` is declared already

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler doesn't complain about the `global_var` outside main. It **only complains about the newly created `global_var` in main** that you don't use. Which you can check by looking at the line number that `go` mentions.

You can try an empty program with a `global_var` outside any function that nobody references: no problems there. And of course, the `usesGlobalVar` function that *does* reference the actual global symbol has nothing to do with the one you create in `main`.

Comment: Search for "golang shadowing". If you redeclare a name from an outer scope in an inner one, you have a brand new variable. Often, as here, it's confusing.

Comment: I suppose := will declare any variable that isn't declared in the local scope. It seems ambiguous but I guess it's just the way things are.